How to have multiple events with a single onclick in javascript
I am veryyy new to this and am trying out a small project while I learn html/css/javascript. So, sorry if this is a fairly obvious question/answer.
Basically, I made my (very simple) site have a dark mode using this set up:
CSS
:root{
    --primary-color: #ffffff;
    --secondary-color: #1d1d1d;
}
.dark-theme{
    --primary-color: #212121;
    --secondary-color: #e0e0e0;
}

I then use primary/secondary for all my background/text colors. Then,
SCRIPT
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

   icon.onclick = function (){
        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
       if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
          icon.src = "/images/sun-2-svgrepo-com.png";
     }else{
        icon.src = "/images/moon-stars-svgrepo-com.png";
   }
}

This is so when someone clicks my moon image tagged "icon" the colors inverse, and "icon" turns into a sun image. This works perfect for my dark mode!
I tried to insert the same process for "icon" underneath to see if it would happen at the onclick also...
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

    var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

    icon.onclick = function (){
        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
        if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
            icon.src = "/images/sun-2-svgrepo-com.png";
            icon2.src = "/images/lightmode.png";
        }else{
            icon.src = "/images/moon-stars-svgrepo-com.png";
            icon2.src = "/images/darkmode.png";
        }
}

it didn't work.
My questions is, is there a way to change my other images (png, used as icons) from their light mode image to dark mode image. Basically, when the moon image changes to the sun image by the click, how can I have my other images switch as well?
Thank you!

You can do the same as you are doing with the moon/sun icon, declare a variable for each image and change in the same if accordingly...

The best way is to use .addEventListener() instead of .onclick. You can add as many event listeners as you like, and all will be called.

@PauloFernando Thank you for your response! I tried this
var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon2");
icon.onclick = function (){
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
        icon2.src = "/images/facebook-outline-svgrepo-com (1) (1).png";
    }else{
        icon2.src = "/images/facebookdark.png";
    }
}

and it didn't work :/

Can you make an example here? https://jsfiddle.net/

You need to change the second icon name from icon to something else, maybe like icon-2 because you cannot have more than one element with the same id in an HTML document.
It should be something like this
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon-2");

 icon.onclick = function (){
        document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
        if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
            icon.src = "/images/sun-2-svgrepo-com.png";
            icon2.src = "/images/lightmode.png";
        }else{
            icon.src = "/images/moon-stars-svgrepo-com.png";
            icon2.src = "/images/darkmode.png";
        }
 }


Your html element should also reflect
 <img id="icon-2" src="" alt=""/>

You are only allowed to use a single name for multiple elements if you are using class in CSS and not for id

Bless you! And thank you soooo much! That was exactly what was wrong! I was using the same id and had the id tag in the  instead of directly in the  like you showed. Seriously, thank you!
